# Spatial kernel density in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, kernel-density

I have the data of the volume per area for Madrid.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
def setColorbar(ax, colormap, vmin, vmax):
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
    # fake up the array of the scalar mappable. Urgh...
    sm._A = []
    return plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)

vmin=0
vmax=70
cmap='jet'
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
dfMd.plot(column='volume', alpha=0.5,ax=ax, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
setColorbar(ax, cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

[image]

I would like to find hotspot of the building density and assign to each polygon a sort of kernel density class associated to the hotspot like this [example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Kernel-density-estimates-A-kernel-density-estimate-and-point-location-of-Lyme-cases_fig1_320599799)

What I have done is to define points of interest based on percentiles in this way.

```
pcts95 = np.percentile(dfMd['volume'], 95)
dfMd95 = dfMd[dfMd['volume'] >= pcts95]
dfMd95 = dfMd95.drop_duplicates(["geometry"]).reset_index(drop=True)
dfMd95 = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in dfMd95.unary_union.geoms])
dfMd95=gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfMd95)
dfMd95.columns = ['geometry']
X=[]
Y=[]
for i in dfMd95.index:
  X.append(dfMd95['geometry'].centroid.x)
  Y.append(dfMd95['geometry'].centroid.y)

vmin=0
vmax=70
cmap='jet'
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
dfMd.plot(column='volume', alpha=0.1,ax=ax, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
setColorbar(ax, cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
ax.scatter(X,Y, color='black', s=75)
```

[image]

However I would like to know if there is a way to estimate kernel density based polygons value as this [example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Kernel-density-estimates-A-kernel-density-estimate-and-point-location-of-Lyme-cases_fig1_320599799)

Comment: What about using a heatmap ?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz `dfMd` is a geopandas dataframe. However the data comes from a raster data. I just converted a geotiff image in a geopandas dataframe to make some correlations.

Comment: @emax are you trying to plot something like this (scroll to bottom)? https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html If you have one point per raster cell, the `weights` parameter might be of interest to you. Your `volume` would be the weight.

Comment: I'm also struggling a bit to understand the question - do you want the density as data or plotted?  Assuming data, is this approach of any use? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368894/density-per-grid-cell

Comment: I would like to assign to each pixel the respective center they belong to based on the distance to the center and the "intensity" of the value. I would like to find a sort of urban polycentricity